Kyocera ECOSYS P5021cdw printer does not work
I cannot get my Kyocera ECOSYS P5021cdw printer to work.
Driver: downloaded from https://www.kyoceradocumentsolutions.eu/en/support/downloads.name-L2V1L2VuL3ByaW50ZXJzL0VDT1NZU1A1MDIxQ0RX.html#tab=driver
Driver package name: Linux Universal Driver (Phase9.3_20230720)
It has a .deb installation package for Ubuntu; I installed it through "Ubuntu Software¨.
The printer is recognized: it appears in the list of printers. When I submit a document for printing, it appears in the list of documents for the printer -- but it does not get printed. The status is "in bewerking" in Dutch, may be "processing" in English?
What is wrong, and how can I fix it? Thanks!
Bart
Edit: Problem fixed; this web page: https://community.spiceworks.com/t/linux-printing-with-kyocera-print-panel/1014129 helped a lot.
